# CakePHP: find associated data with contain

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I'm reading the CakePHP documentation but I'm not sure if I need to use some other methods than `find`. Example:

in my controller I want to provide a filtered list of `Orders` where the `state` field of the related table `OrderStates` is "Open":

```
$orders = $this->ItemsDeliveryNotes->Orders->find('list', [
    'limit' => 200, 
    'conditions' => ['Orders.order_state.state' => 'Open'],
    'contain' => ['OrderStates']
]);
```

but **it says it doesn't find the column `order_state`**.
Here the definition of the table `Orders`:

Creation

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    customer_id int(11),
    orderNumber varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    orderDate date,
    order_state_id int(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY order_state_id (order_state_id),
    CONSTRAINT orders_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT orders_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (order_state_id) REFERENCES order_states (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Entity

```
class Order extends Entity
{
    protected $_accessible = [
        'orderNumber' => true,
        'orderDate' => true,
        'customer_id' => true,
        'order_state_id' => true,
        'customer' => true,
        'order_state' => true,
        'items' => true
    ];
}
```

Table

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('orders');
    $this->setDisplayField('orderNumber');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('Customers', [
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_id'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('OrderStates', [
        'foreignKey' => 'order_state_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Items', [
        'foreignKey' => 'order_id'
    ]);
}

public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['order_state_id'], 'OrderStates'));
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['customer_id'], 'Customers'));

    return $rules;
}
```

and `OrderStates`:

Creation

```
CREATE TABLE order_states (
 id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 state varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 badge varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Entity

```
class OrderState extends Entity
{
    protected $_accessible = [
        'state' => true,
        'badge' => true
    ];
}
```

Table

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('order_states');
    $this->setDisplayField('state');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
}
```

The column `order_state` is accessible within `Orders` and I also added the related table (`OrderStates`) to the `contain` option. What I still miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a working syntax to use:

```
$orders = $this->ItemsDeliveryNotes->Orders->find('list', [ 'limit' => 200 ])
    ->contain('OrderStates')->where(['state' => 'Open']);
```

Answer (score -1):

@mark the issue in your conditions for contained entity. please do confirm which cakephp version you are using.

Here is the example to use the conditions for `contained table`

*Passing Conditions to Contain*

```
// Prior to 3.5.0 you would use contain(['Comments' => function () { ... }])

$query = $articles->find()->contain('Comments', function (Query $q) {
    return $q
        ->select(['body', 'author_id'])
        ->where(['Comments.approved' => true]);
});
```

**Note**: Make sure you have included `use Cake\ORM\Query;` in namespaces section.

For the more detials you can refer to documentation here. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#passing-conditions-to-contain

For your situation it could be something like this.

```
$orders = $this->ItemsDeliveryNotes->Orders->find('list', [ 'limit' => 200 ])->contain('OrderStates', function (Query $q) { return $q->where(['state' => 'Open']); });
```

Comment: I'm using CakePHP 3.7.7

Comment: @Mark in such case the above example could help you.

Comment: $orders = $this->ItemsDeliveryNotes->Orders->find('list', [
    'limit' => 200
])->contain('OrderStates', function (Query $q) { return $q->where(['state' => 'Open']); });

Comment: It returns: "Argument 1 passed to App\Controller\ItemsDeliveryNotesController::App\Controller\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Controller\Query, instance of Cake\ORM\Query given, called in /home/mark/erp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Association.php". Perhaps there is something else to setup?

Comment: Try replace Query with `\Cake\ORM\Query`

Comment: Or add `use Cake\ORM\Query` in namespace includes. I have updated the ans as well.

Comment: It fixes the error, but the query doesn't work as expected. It returns all the records. I'll post the correct solution.

Comment: Previously you were looking for the condition in relationship table `Orders.order_state.state`....the perposed solutions for that.

Comment: It's not fair to downvote just because I didn't accept your solution. Please, read carefully my question: *I want to provide a filtered list of Orders where the state field of the related table OrderStates is "Open"*. Your query just avoid the errors, but doesn't filter the list as requested. It's not a problem, but I cannot accept the answer. I'm sorry.

Comment: It's ok @Mark np, We are here to guid developers in right way! It's not matter you have not accepted the solutions. It's your oppinion. The main question was about to add conditions for relational `contains` table... The provided solutions was for that. I have downvote your solutions because it was not respective of that. it was query on the same table. Not relational.

Comment: For the filtered result... I have added comments for that.

Comment: To understand: why do you say it's not relational? From table `ItemDeliveryNotes` I retrieve data in the related table `Orders` and I filter that.

Comment: The context was not about the ItemDeliveryNotes. As per your question `in my controller I want to provide a filtered list of Orders where the state field of the related table OrderStates is "Open":` Where state field should be inside OrderStatus table not in `Order` table.

Comment: The `Orders` table is contained into `ItemDeliveryNotes` as per my first line of code: `$this->*ItemsDeliveryNotes*->Orders->find(...)`. In fact my solution works: from `ItemsDeliveryNotes` retrieves related `Orders` and filters out the "orders" that have their `OrderStates` "Open"

Comment: I'm just wondering how this line will query from OrderStatus table. `->where(['state' => 'Open'])` this should be add condition on `Orders` table...not?

Comment: `Orders` contains just the `order_state_id` but it's not very handy. So using the `contain` clause I "navigate" to the related table `OrderStates` and use the `state` (verbose) field to filter out the records I need. But at the same time, `Orders` is contained into `ItemDeliveryNotes` through `order_id`.

Comment: Thanks I'm clear with the table structure. but Still I'm not sure on the conditions you have added. `->where(['state' => 'Open'])` it shoud query on orders.state or OrderStatus.state ??

Comment: `OrderStates.state`

Comment: It should not. It will operate on the Orders scope as you are going to query with Order Model... not on it's chield / contains. for the contained objects you must have to specify the conditions as closer function. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#passing-conditions-to-contain

Comment: That's why I marked your solutions is not complete fix.. not the complete acceptable solutions. Refer to the documentation for the more details.

Comment: Understood. Last question: why does it work, then? :-)